# MySql, Use values in subquery within ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query:

```
Insert into target_counts 
            (target_id, email)  
     values (111, 'aa@aa.aa')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                updated = NOW(), 
                ref_count= (SELECT Count(DISTINCT t.id) 
                            FROM targets t
                                INNER join some_other_table sot on sot.target_id = t.id  
                                sot.email = VALUES(email)
                            )
```

but have error

`'Unknown column 'email' in 'on clause''`

is it any chance to use VALUES in  ON DUPLICATE KEY  Subquery?

Comment: Dont you need an `AND` in that JOIN?

Comment: Which table is `email` in? Looks like `target_counts` to me

Comment: If you need a complicated expression like that, then you would need a trigger.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, condition may be in where too, same error.
I need match email from updated row in `target_counts`  as `Values(email)`  and `some_other_table`,
so i match them as 
`sot.email = VALUES(email)`

Comment: I suggest paying more attention to @GordonLinoff comment, He is a bit of an expert on this subject

Comment: Why aren't you doing it like anyone else with `ref_count = ref_count + 1`?

Comment: What is stored in `ref_count` (default value) when the row is inserted (not updated)?